# Can't get custom user meta to show in header

Tags: plugins, functions, themes

I have used Pie Register plugin to add a "Phone" field.

I tried every method in the book (that google fetched for me, so far) to show it but it shows an empty array although the field is not empty and the wordpress backend shows it.

Also, User Meta plugin is able to show the field with its data but I can't get it to show manually in my header file.

Any help is appreciated, I spent hours without any luck doing this! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'phone', true );
```

And pay attantion about that plugin. The plugin is not using any prefixes, so when you'll create a custom filed with same name as any WordPress user_meta, it will override this one.